# Name lookup for local devices using external DNS provider

Tags: networking, dns, lan

I would like to access some devices on my home LAN with a name I choose without running my own nameserver. For example, I would like to access my WiFi camera with a name like `cam0` or `cam0.mydomain.com`, which would map to its local unroutable address (e.g. 192.168.2.128).

I used to do this using DNS provided by Google Domains by creating an A record pointing to 192.168.2.128, but unfortunately Google Domains DNS recently stopped returning unroutable addresses so this no longer works. [@grawity notes below that it is more likely the local router is dropping the response so this is probably due to an automatic firmware update instead.]

Most of my devices use DHCP hostname, and my home router (Google WiFi) provides lookup by name with the `.lan` domain. For example, I can lookup my camera using `dcs-930l.lan`. So I tried changing the DNS A record to a CNAME record that points to `dcs-930l.lan`.

This works just fine on my macOS Mojave machine; I can ping `cam0.mydomain.com`. But it doesn't work on my Debian Jessie box, even though I can look up both `cam0.mydomain.com` and `dcs-930l.lan`:

```
$ dig cam0.mydomain.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Debian <<>> cam0.mydomain.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 3641
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;cam0.mydomain.com.     IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
cam0.mydomain.com.  3291    IN  CNAME   dcs-930l.lan.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.           86396   IN  SOA a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2019090100 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 24 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.2.1#53(192.168.2.1)
;; WHEN: Sun Sep 01 06:43:23 PDT 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 149

$ dig dcs-930l.lan

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Debian <<>> dcs-930l.lan
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 54112
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;dcs-930l.lan.          IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
dcs-930l.lan.       0   IN  A   192.168.2.128

;; Query time: 6 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.2.1#53(192.168.2.1)
;; WHEN: Sun Sep 01 06:43:49 PDT 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 69

$ ping cam0.mydomain.com
ping: cam0.mydomain.com: Name or service not known
```

I also can't use `cam0.mydomain.com` from an Android phone running Oreo, for I assume the same reason.

My questions:

1. Why does this CNAME lookup to a local name work on the Mac and not on Linux or Android?
2. Is this a misuse of DNS?
3. How can I get lookup using descriptive names for local devices to work without changing DNS provider or running my own name server?

As requested in comments, Linux lookup with `-t AAAA`:

```
$ dig -t AAAA cam0.mydomain.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Debian <<>> -t AAAA cam0.mydomain.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 62152
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;cam0.mydomain.com.     IN  AAAA

;; ANSWER SECTION:
cam0.mydomain.com.  3599    IN  CNAME   dcs-930l.lan.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.           86343   IN  SOA a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2019090100 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 61 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.2.1#53(192.168.2.1)
;; WHEN: Sun Sep 01 07:49:46 PDT 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 149

$ dig -t AAAA dcs-930l.lan

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Debian <<>> -t AAAA dcs-930l.lan
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 25898
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;dcs-930l.lan.          IN  AAAA

;; Query time: 3 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.2.1#53(192.168.2.1)
;; WHEN: Sun Sep 01 07:51:19 PDT 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 41
```

And results from OS X where things work:

```
$ dig cam0.mydomain.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> cam0.mydomain.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 21591
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;cam0.mydomain.com.     IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
cam0.mydomain.com.  2871    IN  CNAME   dcs-930l.lan.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.           86378   IN  SOA a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2019090100 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 24 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.2.1#53(192.168.2.1)
;; WHEN: Sun Sep 01 08:01:55 PDT 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 149

$ dig dcs-930l.lan

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> dcs-930l.lan
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 20258
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;dcs-930l.lan.          IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
dcs-930l.lan.       0   IN  A   192.168.2.128

;; Query time: 3 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.2.1#53(192.168.2.1)
;; WHEN: Sun Sep 01 08:02:07 PDT 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 69

$ ping cam0.mydomain.com
PING dcs-930l.lan (192.168.2.128): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.2.128: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=214.733 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.128: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=9.367 ms

--- dcs-930l.lan ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 9.367/112.050/214.733/102.683 ms
```

Comment: Can you do test lookups with `-t AAAA` for the same names, and make sure they are not incorrectly returning NXDOMAIN?

Comment: Which nameservers is your MacOS system using, and can you repeat the same `dig` queries on that system?

Comment: Edited requested lookups into the question. With `-t AAAA` on Linux, it looks like the same answer for `cam0.mydomain.com` and no answer for `dcs-930l.lan`. In all cases, the local router is being used for name service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does this CNAME lookup to a local name work on the Mac and not on Linux or Android?

At least *one* of your problems is a bug in your `.lan` DNS server:

```
$ dig dcs-930l.lan

;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 54112
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; ANSWER SECTION:
dcs-930l.lan.       0   IN  A   192.168.2.128
```

```
$ dig -t AAAA dcs-930l.lan

;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 25898
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
```

The first query returns some records for this name, which means the second query *cannot* return NXDOMAIN, because the name clearly exists. And if NXDOMAIN is returned anyway, the client is allowed to cache the negative response for all record types – overriding any previously cached positive responses.

So if your system queries for A records only, everything works. But if the system queries for AAAA records first and caches the NXDOMAIN response, it won't even bother checking for A later, because it was just told the domain doesn't exist.

(The correct response would be "status: NOERROR", but with zero items in the answer section.)

> Is this a misuse of DNS?

Private IPv4 directly in public DNS domains – certainly not misuse in general. That said, it's often blocked because it's something that *can be* abused by attackers.

CNAME – probably not; however, I'm not sure how the CNAME pointing to an internal name is supposed to be resolved even in the working case.

> How can I get lookup using descriptive names for local devices to work without changing DNS provider or running my own name server?

Make sure the problem is actually with the DNS provider and not with the DNS resolver.

Many routers nowadays have built-in resolvers which deliberately block any "private" IP addresses from appearing in responses for external domain names, in order to guard against DNS 'rebinding' attacks. (That is, it's much more likely that Google Domains *does* return "foo.mydomain.com. A 192.168.2.128" without any complaints, but the router's DNS resolver drops that response.)

Comment: Interesting. Seems very plausible, though I don't have the expertise to know for sure. I'll try to grab packets to verify.

Comment: I rebooted both my Mac and Linux machines (to try to clear any cached DNS results) and captured packets during a `ping cam0.mydomain.com`. The Linux box never even queries for `dcs-930l.lan` - it queries for `A cam0.mydomain.com` and `AAAA cam0.mydomain.com` and then `A cam0.mydomain.com.lan` and `AAAA cam0.mydomain.com.lan`. I notice that the response for `A cam0.mydomain.com` returns NXDOMAIN, despite containing the CNAME answer. Is that also incorrect, in addition to the problem you pointed out?

Comment: Thank you for your super-detailed answer, including your side comment that the router is likely responsible for dropping private addresses from DNS responses.

Comment: The response which contains NXDOMAIN a CNAME record is probably ... correct, as you're querying a resolver which is supposed to chase up the entire CNAME chain and either return the final result or failure. (I don't know for sure, but I tried adding similar test CNAMEs on my own domain and querying through a known good resolver and it did the same.) But on the other hand ... that resolver itself is the .lan nameserver so I'm surprised it's unable to do that. Really I'm not sure.

Comment: Anyway, my guess is that this is exactly the problem – the Linux stub resolver probably expects the upstream server to _always_ chase CNAMEs to the end (like it's supposed to), while the macOS resolver probably finishes the job on its own.